# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'train' error when trying to implement a convolution neural network program using tensorflow in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, mnist

Even though I am super new to the topic, I am trying to implement a CNN program that can be used to recognize images without using Keras. I am currently using python with Jupyter/Google Colab.

After fixing a few other errors that came up in my code, I now have this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py:1761: UserWarning: An interactive session is already active. This can cause out-of-memory errors in some cases. You must explicitly call `InteractiveSession.close()` to release resources held by the other session(s).
  warnings.warn('An interactive session is already active. This can '

Training the model....
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-1af250ed46b3> in <module>()
    108     for i in range(num_iterations):
    109         # Get the next batch of images
--> 110         batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)              #third got an error for this line -
    111         # x_batch, y_batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
    112 

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'train'
```

This is my current code:

```
!pip install tensorflow_datasets
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow
!pip install tensorflow-datasets
!pip install mnist
#!pip install tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist

import argparse
print ('argparse version: ', argparse.__version__)
import mnist
print ('MNIST version: ', mnist.__version__)
import tensorflow_datasets
print ('tensorflow_datasets version: ', tensorflow_datasets.__version__)
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
print ('tf version: ', tf.__version__)
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
#from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data


#def build_arg_parser():
#    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Build a CNN classifier \
#            using MNIST data')
#    parser.add_argument('--input-dir', dest='input_dir', type=str,
#            default='./mnist_data', help='Directory for storing data')
#    return parser

def get_weights(shape):
    data = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(data)

def get_biases(shape):
    data = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(data)

def create_layer(shape):
    # Get the weights and biases
    W = get_weights(shape)
    b = get_biases([shape[-1]])

    return W, b

def convolution_2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
            padding='SAME')

def max_pooling(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
            strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #args = build_arg_parser().parse_args()

    # Get the MNIST data
    mnist = tensorflow_datasets.load('mnist')

    # The images are 28x28, so create the input layer
    # with 784 neurons (28x28=784)
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

    # Reshape 'x' into a 4D tensor
    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

    # Define the first convolutional layer
    W_conv1, b_conv1 = create_layer([5, 5, 1, 32])

    # Convolve the image with weight tensor, add the
    # bias, and then apply the ReLU function
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(convolution_2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)

    # Apply the max pooling operator
    h_pool1 = max_pooling(h_conv1)

    # Define the second convolutional layer
    W_conv2, b_conv2 = create_layer([5, 5, 32, 64])

    # Convolve the output of previous layer with the
    # weight tensor, add the bias, and then apply
    # the ReLU function
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(convolution_2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)

    # Apply the max pooling operator
    h_pool2 = max_pooling(h_conv2)

    # Define the fully connected layer
    W_fc1, b_fc1 = create_layer([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])

    # Reshape the output of the previous layer
    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])

    # Multiply the output of previous layer by the
    # weight tensor, add the bias, and then apply
    # the ReLU function
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

    # Define the dropout layer using a probability placeholder
    # for all the neurons
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

    # Define the readout layer (output layer)
    W_fc2, b_fc2 = create_layer([1024, 10])
    y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

    # Define the entropy loss and the optimizer
    y_loss = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y_loss, logits=y_conv))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)

    # Define the accuracy computation
    predicted = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_loss, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(predicted, tf.float32))

    # Create and run a session
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)

    # Start training
    num_iterations = 21000
    batch_size = 75
    print('\nTraining the model....')
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        # Get the next batch of images
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

        # Print progress
        if i % 50 == 0:
            cur_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict = {
                    x: batch[0], y_loss: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
            print('Iteration', i, ', Accuracy =', cur_accuracy)

        Train on the current batch
        optimizer.run(feed_dict = {x: batch[0], y_loss: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

    # Compute accuracy using test data
    print('Test accuracy =', accuracy.eval(feed_dict = {
            x: mnist.test.images, y_loss: mnist.test.labels,
            keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

I have found a few posts that have the exact same code as I do, but all of their implementations somehow run. I tried looking up solutions, but did not end up finding one that worked for me.

One post I found said that "base dictionaries don't have a 'train' attribute."
This made me curious as to why I then got this error if dictionaries normally don't have these attributes, but others had this same code work.

Another post used the line:

```
x_batch, y_batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
```

instead of the line:

```
batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
```

but neither seemed to work for me. None of the other changes/solutions I tried looking into ended up working either.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this no attribute error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your code is old/out-dated, that's why it doesn't work any more. It is common to TensorFlow library to change very often, and they break interface also often, hence old code stops working.

First, you try to `import mnist`, this is some wrong module, it contains almost no code, and seems unuseful, probably it was useful and working before, but not now.

Also function `mnist.train.next_batch(...)` doesn't work anymore as it is not implemented inside dataset mnist any more, probably it was also working before.

I decided to implement my own helper class `MyDS` that implements all these missing functionalities. Down below is your full corrected code including my class (at the beginning):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
    tf.enable_eager_execution()
    import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

    class MyDS(object):
        class SubDS(object):
            import numpy as np
            def __init__(self, ds, *, one_hot):
                np = self.__class__.np
                self.ds = [e for e in ds.as_numpy_iterator()]
                self.sds = {(k + 's') : np.stack([
                    (e[k] if len(e[k].shape) > 0 else e[k][None]).reshape(-1) for e in self.ds
                ], 0) for k in self.ds[0].keys()}
                self.one_hot = one_hot
                if one_hot is not None:
                    self.max_one_hot = np.max(self.sds[one_hot + 's'])
            def _to_one_hot(self, a, maxv):
                np = self.__class__.np
                na = np.zeros((a.shape[0], maxv + 1), dtype = a.dtype)
                for i, e in enumerate(a[:, 0]):
                    na[i, e] = True
                return na
            def _apply_one_hot(self, key, maxv):
                assert maxv >= self.max_one_hot, (maxv, self.max_one_hot)
                self.max_one_hot = maxv
                self.sds[key + 's'] = self._to_one_hot(self.sds[key + 's'], self.max_one_hot)
            def next_batch(self, num = 16):
                np = self.__class__.np
                idx = np.random.choice(len(self.ds), num)
                res = {k : np.stack([
                    (self.ds[i][k] if len(self.ds[i][k].shape) > 0 else self.ds[i][k][None]).reshape(-1) for i in idx
                ], 0) for k in self.ds[0].keys()}
                if self.one_hot is not None:
                    res[self.one_hot] = self._to_one_hot(res[self.one_hot], self.max_one_hot)
                for i, (k, v) in enumerate(list(res.items())):
                    res[i] = v
                return res
            def __getattr__(self, name):
                if name not in self.__dict__['sds']:
                    return self.__dict__[name]
                return self.__dict__['sds'][name]
        def __init__(self, name, *, one_hot = None):
            self.ds = tfds.load(name)
            self.sds = {}
            for k, v in self.ds.items():
                self.sds[k] = self.__class__.SubDS(self.ds[k], one_hot = one_hot)
            if one_hot is not None:
                maxh = max(e.max_one_hot for e in self.sds.values())
                for e in self.sds.values():
                    e._apply_one_hot(one_hot, maxh)
        def __getattr__(self, name):
            if name not in self.__dict__['sds']:
                return self.__dict__[name]
            return self.__dict__['sds'][name]
            
    # Get the MNIST data
    mnist = MyDS('mnist', one_hot = 'label') # tensorflow_datasets.load('mnist')

    import argparse
    print ('argparse version: ', argparse.__version__)
    #import mnist
    #print ('MNIST version: ', mnist.__version__)
    #import tensorflow_datasets
    print ('tensorflow_datasets version: ', tfds.__version__)
    #import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
    print ('tf version: ', tf.__version__)
    tf.disable_eager_execution()
    tf.disable_v2_behavior()
    #from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data


    #def build_arg_parser():
    #    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Build a CNN classifier \
    #            using MNIST data')
    #    parser.add_argument('--input-dir', dest='input_dir', type=str,
    #            default='./mnist_data', help='Directory for storing data')
    #    return parser

    def get_weights(shape):
        data = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
        return tf.Variable(data)

    def get_biases(shape):
        data = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
        return tf.Variable(data)

    def create_layer(shape):
        # Get the weights and biases
        W = get_weights(shape)
        b = get_biases([shape[-1]])

        return W, b

    def convolution_2d(x, W):
        return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                padding='SAME')

    def max_pooling(x):
        return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

    #args = build_arg_parser().parse_args()

    # The images are 28x28, so create the input layer
    # with 784 neurons (28x28=784)
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

    # Reshape 'x' into a 4D tensor
    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

    # Define the first convolutional layer
    W_conv1, b_conv1 = create_layer([5, 5, 1, 32])

    # Convolve the image with weight tensor, add the
    # bias, and then apply the ReLU function
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(convolution_2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)

    # Apply the max pooling operator
    h_pool1 = max_pooling(h_conv1)

    # Define the second convolutional layer
    W_conv2, b_conv2 = create_layer([5, 5, 32, 64])

    # Convolve the output of previous layer with the
    # weight tensor, add the bias, and then apply
    # the ReLU function
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(convolution_2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)

    # Apply the max pooling operator
    h_pool2 = max_pooling(h_conv2)

    # Define the fully connected layer
    W_fc1, b_fc1 = create_layer([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])

    # Reshape the output of the previous layer
    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])

    # Multiply the output of previous layer by the
    # weight tensor, add the bias, and then apply
    # the ReLU function
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

    # Define the dropout layer using a probability placeholder
    # for all the neurons
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

    # Define the readout layer (output layer)
    W_fc2, b_fc2 = create_layer([1024, 10])
    y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

    # Define the entropy loss and the optimizer
    y_loss = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y_loss, logits=y_conv))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)

    # Define the accuracy computation
    predicted = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_loss, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(predicted, tf.float32))

    # Create and run a session
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)

    # Start training
    num_iterations = 21000
    batch_size = 75
    print('\nTraining the model....')
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        # Get the next batch of images
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

        # Print progress
        if i % 50 == 0:
            cur_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict = {
                    x: batch[0], y_loss: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
            print('Iteration', i, ', Accuracy =', cur_accuracy)

        # Train on the current batch
        optimizer.run(feed_dict = {x: batch[0], y_loss: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

    # Compute accuracy using test data
    print('Test accuracy =', accuracy.eval(feed_dict = {
            x: mnist.test.images, y_loss: mnist.test.labels,
            keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for trying to help!
I made the changes you said to the variable names but im somehow still getting the same " 'dict' object has no attribute 'train' " error.
Is there anything else that would have to be changed?

Comment: @adigioia Just search for word `mnist` in your whole code. I'm sure you're using it as variable (not module) not just in one place, but in several. I just showed you example of just one wrong usage, the rest you have to search for yourself. General rule - if you import module named `x` then don't use variable named `x` anywhere in the code, otherwise your module name will be overwritten or shadowed.

Comment: @adigioia Also, I see you're using Jupyter notebook. That's why your variable named `mnist` is cached in cells state. You need to clear state of notebook and re-run all of the cells.

Comment: @adigioia Sorry, I found out that your installed module `pip install mnist` is something totally wrong, it doesn't contain almost any code. Probably it is not evey tensorflow related. You have to find and use some other module. I'll try to search correct module for you to do such things.

Comment: Almost all of this code was pre-written and given to me by a professor to edit and use for a research project, so I have to go through and fix any bugs first. I actually just reloaded and was searching for mnist in the rest of the code right before I saw your comments - that was definitely a good call!
Now I am getting the same error but it says mnist has no 'train' attribute instead, so I am now trying to look into that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I definitely appreciate you helping me search! Since this code was given to me to use as is, it makes it a little hard to have to go and try to backtrack what the writer had done to then be able to fix it

Comment: @adigioia That is very common thing to TensorFlow, they change and break interfaces and modules structure very often, so even a bit-outdated code often doesn't run anymore. It seems to me that the module that was used in your code (MNIST) is not the same anymore. Now we have to find the new correct location of it, somewhere inside tensorflow package. Probably functions have changed too inside this module.

Comment: Oh okay, I had no idea since this is the very first time I have had to work with any of these packages or CNNs before. It seems a little strange to me that people would continue to do this if the chances of the code running are slim (whether it be from being slightly outdated to there being other issues). Currently, I have tensorflow 2.4.0 installed which, from looking it up now, seems to be the newest version. I'm having some trouble trying to find other packages to replace mnist but I will definitely keep searching as well!

Comment: I ended up finding another package called python-mnist from here https://pypi.org/project/python-mnist/ . I then went back to my code and changed my install to be !pip install python-mnist. I then changed my import to be from mnist import MNIST. Next, I went to my code and every time mnist.~~~ came up, I changed it to be MNIST. I now have the error " type object 'MNIST' has no attribute 'train' " on the same batch line.

Comment: However, I now have a TON of warning messages that popped up talking about all these different things being deprecated. I'm assuming since it came up saying so many things are deprecated that this goes along with what you were saying about how the code I was given is probably old and that's why it no longer works as it should?

Comment: @adigioia I figured out that all missing functionality was just removed in latest TensorFlow. That's why I decided to re-implement them from scratch. See my updated answer, it includes my helper class `MyDS` that contains all that was missing. My class is integrated into your code, and full corrected your code is located in my answer. As you're using Jupyter notebook, after copy-pasting my code you need to reset environment, there is in menu a button like `Reload/Reset environment and run all cells`. In my Colab notebook code works perfectly well and after training gives accuracy `0.988`.

Comment: I definitely owe you a huge thank you for being able to do all of this and help me!! I had spent awhile after my last comments trying to keep looking for other packages, but still ended up empty handed, so your comment/answer is a huge relief! After having the program fun for 30-40 minutes, I stopped execution around the 11,000th or so iteration and got individual iteration accuracies anywhere from 0.82 (from 100th iteration) to 1.0 (for many other iterations).

Comment: I tried to comment out the print iteration progress section to see if that would make the program run faster but I ended up getting an error that said value error: tf.enable_eager_execution should be called at start." Not sure why because I still used your exact same code I had just ran on, but either way, the program works great - thank you so much!

Comment: @adigioia This error is unrelated to print function.The reason is simple - because Jupyter Notebook system keeps everything in memory.So if you run cells again they're run starting from same global state,with all variables already filled in.In other words running all cells twice is not the same.Running twice is same as appending source code twice to same script and running.Definitely second half of code may be non-runnable after first half. In other words if you're re-running code then you have to reset all environment.There is in menu something like `Reset/Clear environment and run all cells`

Comment: @adigioia BTW, you're saying that your training takes half hour. You can upload your script (as I did) to Google's website [https://colab.research.google.com](https://colab.research.google.com), this service is free if you have GMail account, and allows you to use for free (unlimited time) quite powerful GPU. There is in menu something like `Environment / Select environment` and there you can select GPU. By default GPU environment is not enabled, CPU is used. I've uploaded my script from answer and it took around 3-5 minutes to run on theirs GPU.

Comment: I went back to Google Colab and just tried your suggestion about switching to GPU! If you go to the Runtime tab, then there is an option that says "Change runtime type" and in there is where you can then choose GPU or TPU. It definitely was a lot faster - maybe 3 or 4 minutes at max! All of your comment/answers were BEYOND helpful and I definitely learned a lot from this post! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @adigioia Welcome! :) And Marry Christmas and Happy New Year!

Comment: Thank you!! I hope you had a great Christmas and will have a great New Year too :)